# How can I get an organized list from module re in python?

Tags: python, module

The problem I try to solve is to get from a molecule compositon (ex. CO2, H20, SO4) their atomic weight. To achive this I'm using module re to separate all the parts from the string and module chemistry to find the weight of the atom (ex. C O H Na).
*The atomic weight is calculated by multipliying the weight of the atom by the number on the left. (ex. H2O = 1x2 + 16x1).

```
def mol_weigth(molecule):
    e_list = []
    result = 0
    e_list.append(re.findall("([A-Z][a-z]{0,1})", molecule))
```

I managed to find the compunds and append it to a list (e_list), but I can't find a way of finding all the numbers in a way that I can use them to calculate with them.

Comment: `([A-Z][a-z]{0,1})(\d*)` I would think should work ...

Comment: Btw, e_list = re.findall(...) seems simpler and better, else you'll have a list in a list. And no need for result = 0 either, result = sum([atom_weight[i[0]]*(int(i[1]) if i[1] else 1) for i in e_list]) will do the trick. atom_weight being a dict of {atom:weight}